# Calculate amount after interest over time SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
Initial Amount = $100
Interest Rate = 5%
Number of years = 3
```

Total Amount = $115.76

How would I calculate this in Sql Server?

Comment: I think you should be having Start Date or End Date to do this in sql server.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to put an answer together based on your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I calculated total amount:

```
DECLARE @Current_LeaseEndDate DATE = '01/31/2021'  --3 Years
DECLARE @PercentIncrease  FLOAT = .05
DECLARE @Principal FLOAT = 100

SELECT 
YEAR(DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@Current_LeaseEndDate AS VARCHAR(10))) + 1),
CASE WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@Current_LeaseEndDate AS VARCHAR(10))) + 1) >= YEAR(GETDATE())
        THEN @Principal * POWER((1 + @PercentIncrease), YEAR(DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@Current_LeaseEndDate AS VARCHAR(10))) + 1) - YEAR(GETDATE()))
        END AS MEH
```